# What is happening with my data, as I recover them from SQLite?

Tags: python

Unfortunately I have some speed data saved as TEXT in SQLite. I wish to select the max speed for every userid, and this is making it hard for me. When I try to output max(speed) on my list after I have retrieved it I get a value that is not present in my database.

So, here is how I retrieve my data:

```
def getMaxSpeed(databasepath, id):
    con = lite.connect(databasepath)
    speeds = []
    with con:
        cur = con.execute("SELECT speed FROM table where userid = {userid}".format(userid=id))
    speed = [x[0] for x in cur]
    for i in range(0,len(speed)):
        speeds.append(float(speed[i]))
    return speeds
```

Sample (cropped) output before the for-loop:

```
[u'0.00', u'0.20', u'0.20', u'0.20', u'0.10', u'0.20', u'0.10', u'0.10', u'0.20', u'13.60', u'12.30', u'12.20', u'12.30', u'12.20', u'13.00', u'13.00', u'13.00', u'13.00', u'13.60', u'13.60', u'13.70', u'14.00', u'13.10', u'6.90', u'7.50', u'7.60', u'7.70', u'6.00', u'5.90', u'8.10', u'8.10', u'8.10', u'8.30', u'8.20', u'4.60', u'1.70', u'1.70', u'3.10', u'3.90', u'3.60', u'3.50', u'3.50', u'3.30', u'3.30', u'3.30', u'2.00', u'2.00', u'2.10', u'2.10', u'3.70', u'3.60', u'3.50', u'3.50', u'3.30', u'6.00', u'4.20', u'4.20', u'4.30', u'4.20', u'4.30', u'4.30', u'4.20', u'4.20', u'4.70', u'4.80', u'5.00', u'6.40', u'6.40', u'5.10', u'5.10', u'2.20', u'2.20', u'2.20', u'2.20', u'0.00', u'0.10', u'0.10', u'0.30', u'0.10', u'0.10', u'0.10', u'0.20', u'0.00', u'13.20', u'10.50', u'10.50']
```

Sample (cropped) output after the for loop:

```
[0.0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 13.6, 12.3, 12.2, 12.3, 12.2, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.6, 13.6, 13.7, 14.0, 13.1, 6.9, 7.5, 7.6, 7.7, 6.0, 5.9, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.3, 8.2, 4.6, 1.7, 1.7, 3.1, 3.9, 3.6, 3.5, 3.5, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 2.0, 2.0, 2.1, 2.1, 3.7, 3.6, 3.5, 3.5, 3.3, 6.0, 4.2, 4.2, 4.3, 4.2, 4.3, 4.3, 4.2, 4.2, 4.7, 4.8, 5.0, 6.4, 6.4, 5.1, 5.1, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.0, 13.2, 10.5, 10.5]
```

Main method:

```
speed = []
for id in userid:
    speed = getMaxSpeed(dbpath, id)
    for x in speed:
        if x > 40:
           print x
           print id
           break
```

The last for loop is just to do some checking for erroneous data. It outputs a lot of different ID's where every speed equal 102.3. I expect my speeds to be between 0 and 30.

Sample output:

```
102.3
209407000
```

So, to check this is go back to my database and do:

```
SELECT distinct speed from table WHERE userid = 209407000
```

It outputs a lot of speeds,http://pastebin.com/bEe5tPkZ , no one near 102.3. So, something is happening in my retrieval method - but what? I'm having one of these days where everything just go wrong.

Comment: I don't like this piece of code `speed += getMaxSpeed(dbpath, id)`

Comment: Sorry, that was from a wild try to assure that it was a list. I've fixed that, but the problem persist. I have edited my main post.

Comment: more pythonic `return [ float(x[0]) for x in cur]` and you don't need `for` construct to transform the data to float